# R Text Analysis Question

Tags: r, text-mining

Let's say I have a text file I read into R: it contains 5 separate transcripts of lectures. Each transcript is separated from another by a common symbol on a line" "~~", how would I create a list with 5 elements, each element being a character vector containing one of those separate transcripts?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scan`.

E.g. `x <- scan("data.txt", what="character", sep="~")`

Note that the `sep` argument must be one byte.

Comment: Given the one byte issue, you could scan w/o separating the text, & then run `strsplit(x, "~~")`.